# C# ввод двумерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив NxN, нужно ввести его по след формату
массив размером N = 3

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9
```

Начал с

```
int[,] a = new int[101,101]; // исправил)

string[] s = new string[101];  
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
   s[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

теперь нужно..

```
s[i] в int a[i]
```

как?

Comment: Непонятно почему **int[] a = new int[101]**
Если вы говорите двумерный массив 3х3

Comment: если у вас двумерный массив 3х3, то зачем вам одномерные массивы размером в 101 элемент? В чем вообще логика?

Comment: ой ошибка, там где int[] a = new int[101]; я ошибся, там int[,] a = new int[101,101]; по задаче n от 1 до 100, я задачу решил, а система проверяющая задачи (timus judge) требует правильного формата вводных данных, то есть ввод по строкам и столбцам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив size х size

```
        Console.Write("Введите размер массива: ");
        int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        int[,] myMassive = new int[size, size];
        for (int i = 0; i < myMassive.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string enterString = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] massiveString = enterString.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
            for (int j = 0; j < massiveString.Length; j++)
            {
                myMassive[i, j] = int.Parse(massiveString[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: то что вы привели выше есть: http://i.imgur.com/b2YoCoZ.png
а в моем случае требуется построчный вывод до massive3x3.GetLnegth(1) massive3x3.GetLength(0)-раз - > http://i.imgur.com/zxyoVFu.png
Если бы мне нужен был 1 вариант, я бы не задавал такие глупые вопросы)

Comment: Построчный вывод? Или все же построчный ввод?

Comment: построчный ввод, в случае просто ввода в строку(К примеру введите два числа через пробел) я пользовался способом
string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); 
Но здесь целочисленный двумерный массив и я без понятия как быть

Comment: То есть у вас получается строка:

1 2 3 4 5 6 и т.д.,

 где одна строка есть числа введенные через пробел. Эту строку надо парсить в массив int. Я верно понимаю?

Comment: Да  
пользователь вводит число n (размер массива nxn) 
а затем вводит сам массив
4  
1 3 6 10  
2 5 9 13  
4 8 12 15  
7 11 14 16

Comment: Поправил ответ. Еще надо учесть то, что пользователь может вводить неправильную строку :)

Comment: Большое спасибо) Очень помогли!) Учитывать не обязательно, тимус не проверяет на неправильные входные данные.)

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен ввод в одну строку, то можно сделать так:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Input first dimension");
    string rawFirstDimension = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Input second dimension");
    string rawSecondDimension = Console.ReadLine();

    int firstDimension;
    int secondDimension;

    // провекрка корректности размеров массива
    if (!int.TryParse(rawFirstDimension, out firstDimension) ||
        !int.TryParse(rawSecondDimension, out secondDimension))
        throw new Exception("Parsing failed");

    var array = new int[firstDimension, secondDimension];

    string rawStr = Console.ReadLine();
    if (rawStr == null) // проверка массива на пустоту
        throw new Exception("Array is empty");

    var rawArray = rawStr.Split(' ');

    // проверка на соответствие массива требуемой размерности
    if(rawArray.Length != firstDimension * secondDimension)
        throw new Exception("Wrong array size");

    for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondDimension; j++)
        {
            int next;
            if (int.TryParse(rawArray[i * secondDimension + j], out next))
                array[i, j] = next;
            else
              throw new Exception("Parsing failed");//если очередной элемент не число
        } 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Array is");
    for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondDimension; j++)
            Console.Write(array[i, j]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Возьму на заметку)

Answer (score 2):

Ввод с клавиатуры массива 2х2 и вывод в консоль

```
        int[,] numbers = new int[2,2];

        for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
                numbers[n,m] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(numbers[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
```